# Getting multiple columns where max value is selected and showing multiple columns in select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query trouble for SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    ProductNumber, 
    AlternativeProductNumber,
    MAX(stockBalanse.physicalStockBalanse) 'PhysicalStock'
FROM 
    alternativeProducts
LEFT JOIN 
    stockBalanse ON stockBalanse.Productnumber = alternativeProducts.AlternativeProductNumber
GROUP BY
    ProductNumber
```

Example results:

In this case I want the outcome to be one line left

prod1     altprod3  30

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>productnumber</th>
    <th>alternateProductNumber</th>
    <th>physicalStockValue</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>prod1</td>
    <td>altprod1</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>prod1</td>
    <td>altprod2</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>prod1</td>
    <td>altprod3</td>
    <td>30</td>
</table>
```

Some information on this table: this table is an extension of my product table.
I have many different alternative products for some of the products.

What I am trying to do here: I want to group by `productnumber` (so that only distinct values are left here).

And I want to show the alternative that has the highest `physicalStockBalanse`.

So quick summary here:

I want each `productnumber` to only display the alternative product number witch has the highest `stockbalanse`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation:

```
SELECT ap.ProductNumber, sb.AlternativeProductNumber,
       MAX(sb.physicalStockBalanse) as PhysicalStock
FROM ap.alternativeProducts LEFT JOIN 
     stockBalanse sb
     ON sb.Productnumber = ap.AlternativeProductNumber
GROUP BY ap.ProductNumber, sb.AlternativeProductNumber;
```

There is no reason to select both product numbers.  The `JOIN` guarantees that they are the same value or the second is `NULL`.